# Android - Erro ao renomear pacote no android

Tags: java, android, xml

Estou tentando alterar o nome do pacote com.app3 para com.jogoPedraTesoura quando tento subir para google play console. Recebo a mensagem que o nome do com.app3 deve ser alterado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro do XMl. Manifest tem esta assim: [image: package="com.jogopedratesoura"]

Porém tenho essa informação no aba Merged do Manifest.XML:[image: package="com.app3"]

Como alterar o nome do pacote nestas condições ???

Comment: Segui os passos nesta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Já alterou no build.gradle (app)?